# Anime where a kid's mom and sister get eaten in front of him, so he vows to take revenge against the monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

The boy's mother hides him and his sister, but two monsters manage to enter the house. They devour the mother, and upon finding the children, tear his sister into pieces, consuming her liver, heart, and meat. After finishing their gruesome meal, the monsters decide not to eat the boy, claiming that human men flesh tastes bad. The boy vows to take revenge against the monsters. Both the boy and his sister appear to be around 3 to 4 years old. I remember watching the first two episodes of the anime, but I can't recall the name because it's in Japanese. Can anyone tell me the name of this anime?

Comment: That sounds like a scene from *Sacrificial Princess and the King of Beasts* (Niehime to Kemono no Ou) but it's not in the first few episodes, that scene occurs much later. Have a look at https://myanimelist.net/anime/46422/Niehime_to_Kemono_no_Ou?q=sacrificial%20princess&cat=anime and see if it looks familiar.

Comment: @songoku Did you ever get a chance to check out Sacrificial Princess and the King of Beasts?

Comment: Micheal  Stimson your right it was  sacrificial princess and the king of the beasts

Comment: Just checked he it was Sacrificial Princess and the King of Beasts

Comment: @songoku You should be able to post that as an answer and accept it, to mark to others that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Sacrificial Princess and the King of Beasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrificial_Princess_and_the_King_of_Beasts)* is the answer

[image: Front cover of Sacrificial Princess and the King of Beasts]

> The King of the Beasts and Demons regularly receives female human sacrifices to eat in order to assert the dominance of his people over the human race. However, for the 99th sacrifice, the human girl brought to the capital, Sariphi, intrigues the Beast King. In fact she isn't afraid of him or any other beast and even accepts her death without begging or crying as she has neither home nor family to return to if she were released. The King finds her intriguing and let her stay at his side as his consort despite being human. This is the story of how Sariphi will become the queen of the demons and beasts.

It may be episode 7, "A Boy of Love and Hate":

> Bennu joins Gwiber and Leonhart and uses his connection to Sariphi to track her (Gwiber translates Bennu's speech for Leonhart). While Ilya carries an unwilling Sariphi on horseback, they get attacked by a pack of hyena-men. Ilya kills them, but when he attempts to kill a child among them, Sariphi helps the child escape and asks why he would go this far. He says all beasts are evil and confesses that he is in love with her. She sadly refuses him and says that there are good and evil beasts, just like humans. He retorts that before they met, **beasts killed and ate his mother and little sister Misha**, and for that, he will never rest until the beasts are exterminated.

[image: Beasts stating the "Young males still taste like crap" as Ilya lies on the ground beside the blood from his mother and sister]